# Partial is rendered twice in ActiveAdmin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

My partial is being rendered twice: at the top of the page and at the place where it's supposed to.
Apparently, this only happens when I have ActiveAdmin-specific code (table_for).

Any help is greatly appreciated. 
Below are some code snippets I'm using.

**In my active admin file:**

```
panel "Children - SubProcesses" do
    text_node link_to "New", new_admin_sub_process_node_path(:parent_id => process_node.id)
    div render :partial => "/admin/process_nodes/child_list", :locals => { :parent => process_node }
end
```

**In _child_list.html.erb file**

```
<%=
unless parent.children.empty?
table_for parent.children do 
    column :id
    column :name
    column "Actions" do |child_node|
            text_node link_to "View", admin_process_node_path(child_node)
            text_node " "
            text_node link_to "Edit", edit_admin_process_node_path(child_node)
            text_node " "
            text_node link_to "Delete", admin_process_node_path(child_node),  :method => :delete, :confirm => "Delete?"
    end
end
end
%>
```

Comment: Probably the first thing you did, but have you searched your project for something like "/admin/process_nodes/child_list" to see if you're accidentally rendering the partial in some other view as well?

Comment: Where does the panel method get called, either directly or indirectly in your code? Please quote the code where it is called.

Answer (score 5):

From what I've read, ActiveAdmin will automatically get the path of the partial based on the current model/resource name. Which means passing `"child_list"` will result in

`"/admin/process_nodes/_child_list.html.erb"`.

Usage would be

```
div render "child_list", :locals {  :parent => process_node }
```

Also, it seems like it would be better to include your `unless` statement within the ActiveAdmin panel block. Then you won't have to add an unnecessary render call if there are no sub processes.

```
panel "Children - SubProcesses" do
    text_node link_to "New", new_admin_sub_process_node_path(:parent_id => process_node.id)

    unless parent.children.empty?
        div render "child_list", :locals {  :parent => process_node }
    end
end
```

Finally, I don't know if using a partial is a great benefit. I don't know if you have anything else in the partial, but you could write it this way.

```
panel "Children - SubProcesses" do
  text_node link_to "New", new_admin_sub_process_node_path(:parent_id => process_node.id)

  unless parent.children.empty?
    table_for parent.children do 
      column :id
      column :name
      column "Actions" do |child_node|
        text_node link_to "View", admin_process_node_path(child_node)
        text_node " "
        text_node link_to "Edit", edit_admin_process_node_path(child_node)
        text_node " "
        text_node link_to "Delete", admin_process_node_path(child_node),  :method => :delete, :confirm => "Delete?"
        end
    end
  end
end
```